# How to check if executables which going to be installed is 32 or 64 bit in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

How to check if executables which going to get installed is 32 or 64 bit in PowerShell?

Is there any predefined function within powershell to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many advanced [PE header](https://www.google.com/#q=powershell+get+executable+pe+header) parsers for PowerShell.

Here's a simple function that just reads [Machine Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680313(v=vs.85).aspx) field:

```
function Is64bit([string]$path) {
    try {
        $stream = [IO.File]::OpenRead($path)
    } catch {
        throw "Cannot open file $path"
    }
    $reader = [IO.BinaryReader]$stream

    if ($reader.ReadChars(2) -join '' -ne 'MZ') { throw 'Not an executable' }

    $stream.position = 0x3C
    $stream.position = $reader.ReadUInt32() # go to COFF
    if ($reader.ReadUInt32() -ne 0x00004550) { throw 'Not a PE executable' }

    return $reader.ReadUInt16() -eq 0x8664 # machine type
}
```

Usage:

```
Is64bit C:\Windows\explorer.exe
```